# Imagelist with gifs

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-2.0, animated-gif

I made my own control, and this control allows to have a image for loading. Its has some images preloaded inside, and I want to allow the programmers using this control to select which image they want.

My first try was to use a `ImageList`, but since it doesn't not accept GIFs images I need a workarround. The control shows the GIF in a `PictureBox`.

My question is: there is any way to expose the images to the visual IDE as a property in the same way that `ImageList` do (selecting images like a `ComboBox` with a little preview) without using a Imagelist?

Comment: You'll have to make your own UITypeEditor.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just if someone need the solution:

```vb
<TypeConverter(GetType(ImageKeyConverter))> _
<RelatedImageList("LoadingImageList")> _
<Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ImageIndexEditor, System.Design", GetType(Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))> _
<Description("Imagen de carga que se mostrará en el control cuando se indique.")> _
Public Property LoadingImageKey() As String
    Get
        Return sPic
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        sPic = value
    End Set
End Property
```

And for adding the GIFs images into the ImageList, I added them to the resources and load them into the Imagelist on the creation of the control. I have a secondary var to hold the GIFS and the images are related with a string key:

```vb
Private Sub SysInfoControl_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim result As Resources.ResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)

    If pics.Count = 0 Then
        For Each elem As DictionaryEntry In result
            If elem.Value.GetType Is GetType(Bitmap) Then
                pics.Add(elem.Key.ToString(), CType(elem.Value, Bitmap))
                ImageList1.Images.Add(elem.Key.ToString(), CType(elem.Value, Bitmap))
            End If
        Next
        If pics.ContainsKey(sPic) Then picBoxLoading.Image = pics(sPic)
    End If
End Sub
```

Example of the result:

[image]